# Mokito Annotation @Mock, @InjectMocks not working

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Hi I am new to Mokito and currently following an online tutorial, I have a very basic mokito test set up like this without using annotation:

```
class SomeBusinessMockTest {
    @Test
    public void testfindGreatestFromAllData() {
        DataService dataServiceMock = mock(DataService.class);
        when(dataServiceMock.retreiveAllData()).thenReturn(new int[] {24,1,2});
        SomeBusinessImpl businessImpl = new SomeBusinessImpl(dataServiceMock);
        int result = businessImpl.findGreatestFromAllData();
        assertEquals(24, result);
    }

}
```

This works and gives a green bar, however when I tried to use annotation instead :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class SomeBusinessMockTest {
    
    @Mock
    DataService dataServiceMock; 
    
    @InjectMocks
    SomeBusinessImpl businessImpl;
    
    @Test
    public void testfindGreatestFromAllData() {
        when(dataServiceMock.retreiveAllData()).thenReturn(new int[] {24,1,2});
        int result = businessImpl.findGreatestFromAllData();
        assertEquals(24, result);
    }

}
```

This keeps giving me NullPointer Exception at the line `when(dataServiceMock.retreiveAllData()).thenReturn(new int[] {24,1,2});` Not sure what is going on, seems like the only thing I change is how the mock object are being initialized.
To give a complete but optional context, here is the SomeBusinessImpl.java and DataService interface :

```
public class SomeBusinessImpl {
    // someBusinessImpl depends on interface DataService to work 
    // so would need to check 
    
    private DataService dataService;

    public SomeBusinessImpl(DataService dataService) {
        super();
        System.out.println("dsadsadsadasdas");
        this.dataService = dataService;
    }

    int findGreatestFromAllData() {
        int[] data = dataService.retreiveAllData();
        int greatest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        dataService.retreiveAllData();
        for (int value : data) {
            System.out.println(value);
            if (value > greatest) {
                greatest = value;
            }
        }
        return greatest;
    }

}

interface DataService{
    int[] retreiveAllData();
}
```

Is this somehow related to Junit and Mockito version problem or am I missing something really obvious.
Thanks

Comment: JUnit4 or 5? Can you show your imports in your test class?

Answer (score -1):

I got confused because when I added the @RunWith tag, the IDE asks me to add JUnit4 to the build path, but the from spring starter.io, the spring version I chose is 2.3.5 which uses Junit5, so in order to do this in Junit5 :

```
package com.example.mokito.mokitodemo;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SomeBusinessTest {
    
    @Mock
    DataService dataService;
    
    @InjectMocks
    SomeBusinessImple someBusinessImple;

    @Test
    void testfindTheGreatestFromAllData() {

         when(dataService.retrieveAllData()).thenReturn(new int[] {24,1,2});
         //SomeBusinessImple someBusinessImple = new SomeBusinessImple();
         //someBusinessImple.setDataService(dataService);
         int result = someBusinessImple.findTheGreatestFromAllData();
         assertEquals(24,result);
         
    }

}
```